# Load a UIImageView in separate thread from Disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

I need to load some images into a UIScrollView that is paging. I am using ASIHTTP so loading from the internet is already asynchronous, however I'm trying to load images from disk if i have them cached there but I don't know how to load those asynchronously (It lags between pages)

Is there any easy method that I can use without having to implement full multithreading? 
Can anyone link me some good documents on how to do something like this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use...

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doStuff) withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(someMethod) withObject:nil];`

There are other methods too for multithreading. Here's [Apple's Guide on Multithreading](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html).